# How to save content from textarea as array, and save in another php file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have two files: index.php (also contains JS)
And page2.php.

I have in index.php a textarea:

```
<textarea id="url" rows="1" class="form-control" style="color: white; width:20%; height:3.50%; text-align:center; background-color:#2c2c2d; resize:none;" placeholder="url here"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="enviar();" value="Start"/>
```

And in page2.php i have:

```
$url = "$url";
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

I want to actually create a connection between them, with the help of js.

That as soon as I write in the textbox the url (index.php) and press submit,

page2 will accept the $url from the textbox.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without js. Just use form.

### HTML

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<textarea id="url" rows="1" class="form-control" style="color: white; width:20%; height:3.50%; text-align:center; background-color:#2c2c2d; resize:none;" placeholder="url here" name="url"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start"/>
</form>
```

### PHP

```
$url = $_POST["url"]; //You will get value here
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

### Update

**Index.php file**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["url"]) && $_POST["url"] != ''){
$_SESSION["url"] = $_POST["url"];
}
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <textarea id="url" rows="1" class="form-control" style="color: white; width:20%; height:3.50%; text-align:center; background-color:#2c2c2d; resize:none;" placeholder="url here" name="url"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Start"/>
    </form>
```

**In page2.php**

```
  <?php
   session_start();
   if(isset($_SESSION["url"]) && $_SESSION["url"] != ''){
    $url = $_SESSION["url"];
   }else{
    $url = '';
   }
   $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check now

Comment: I checked, but it takes me to page2, I just want that it keep the textarea url as $url, and then use it on page2 (without redirect to page2)

Comment: You can use session for this purpose. Check my updated answer. @elison

Comment: This one works great! also if i want that its save without submit how to do it? save as typing

Comment: Without submit you will need AJAX. :) @elison